# How to find corresponding numbers in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a column with 120 serial numbers and i have the same column with the same numbers another time, but now there are 2 numbers missing. But in the column with the 2 missing numbers, i also have the typenumber.
My boss wants me to get the typenumbers next to the correct serial number of the first column.
thanks

Example image:

[image]

Comment: This is a little confusing.  Please mock up an example with expected outcome.  Also show what you have tried to accomplish this goal.  Remember we do not have your knowledge of the problem, and what you said may make sense to you as you know the problem, but the explanation is a little lacking for us

Comment: it's my english thats lacking, sorry for that

Comment: Even a better reason to mock up some data, it transcends the language barrier.

Comment: added an example

Comment: Simple VLOOKUP will do it then.

Answer (score 0):

Copy one of the columns into the sheet with the other column and then use VLOOKUP.

Like A and B have the serial numbers and type, C has serial numbers with 2 more rows then:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1;A:B;2;2)
```

Into Col D should do it

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like below, enter the formula in cell `B2` and drag it down,

[image]

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,D:D,0),1),"/")
```